# Bootstrap grid going vertical instead of Horizontal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am probably doing this completely wrong but from my understanding I think I am on the right path.

I am trying to make my image grid go side by side in a Horizontal line but instead it's going vertical all the way down my page.

[image]

Here's the current code I am using.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="1" height="150" width="150">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="2" height="150" width="150">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="3" height="150" width="150">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="4" height="150" width="150">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images are going down because, it is the actual behaviour of `col-md-3` bootstrap class. The `col-md-3` doesnt have the size to contain all the four images and thus it goes down.

if you want the images to be horizontally aligned, you have to rewrite your html as

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="1" height="150" width="150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="2" height="150" width="150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="3" height="150" width="150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="4" height="150" width="150">
    </div>
</div>
```

### See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/45Lzks0f/1/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 1):

You want to take all horizontal space having a grid of four images. So you basically want 4 columns. Since twitter-bootstrap is based on a grid of 12, every column should take 3.

Your row should look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="1" height="150" width="150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="2" height="150" width="150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="3" height="150" width="150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="4" height="150" width="150">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="1" height="150" width="150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="1" height="150" width="150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="1" height="150" width="150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="1" height="150" width="150">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an inline list inside a larger column. Which has padding in between each list item. This provides a nicer look.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNboJz

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li>
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="1" height="150" width="150">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="2" height="150" width="150">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="3" height="150" width="150">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SLUyAtG.png" alt="4" height="150" width="150">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```